# How does JVM deal with duplicate JARs of different versions

Tags: java

When there were duplicate JARs with different versions, the behavior was very inconsistent. Does anyone know how the JVM deals with duplicates?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The classloader searches the classpath in order, and uses the first matching class it finds.

Comment: In general this is correct.  However, it depends on the implementation of the classloader.  For example, when loading classes within a web framework the deployed jar/war/ear/sar files may be checked before the official classpath.

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, this is an example of a larger topic (modularity) that is addressed by [OSGi](http://blog.springsource.com/2008/02/18/creating-osgi-bundles/) and [Project Jigsaw/JSR 294](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/) in <s>JDK 7</s> [Java 9](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2878952/java-platform/modularity-in-java-9.html).

Your question is good motivation for the topic: the venerable, simple classpath may have been a good idea at its inception, but it is certainly a pain point in today's age of high dependence on 3rd-party-libraries.

Comment: Jigsaw is actually not in JDK 7 but planned for yet unreleased JDK 9. FWIW I submitted an edit to this factual mistake but it got rejected (not by the author) because it "made no sense as an edit" and "denatured the original intent of the post"