# Is it OK for a jar file to appear twice in the classpath?

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I have a bunch of jars in a folder and in order to streamline the classpath setup I'm using the new (in Java 6) classpath wildcard syntax:

`CLASSPATH=":/$JARS/*"`

which will pick up all jars in the $JARS directory. So far so good.

However, there's one jar in that directory that I need to appear first in the classpath and the docs for the wildcard syntax state that the order of the jars is implementation dependent and cannot be relied upon.

What I was thinking of doing was adding the one jar I need to appear first explicitly, in front of the wildcard:

`CLASSPATH=":/$JARS/first.jar:/$JARS/*"`

Now that would mean that `first.jar` would appear twice in the classpath, first the explicit reference and then with the wildcard. Is that going to cause me any problems?

Yes, I know that I could put `first.jar` into a different directory to avoid the problem but lets just say that doing that would involve a lot of hassle that I'd rather not have to deal with (I'm dealing with a 3rd party product).

**EDIT:**
I need the jar to appear first because it contains some XML configuration files (which are loaded as resources) which need to override XML files with the same name in another jar (supplied by the 3rd party vendor). Just to clarify, `first.jar` is the only jar under my control. All the other jars in the directory are supplied by the 3rd party vendor.

Comment: Why do you need it to appear first?

Comment: @GuillaumePolet I edited my question to respond to your comment.

Comment: Then, a cleaner solution would be to put your ressources in a dedicated folder /com/mycompany/README.txt (just an example) so that you can be sure that it is actually yours that is loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the same jars/classes can appear multiple times on the classpath. The jvm searches them in order.

more info at this question: [How does JVM deal with duplicate JARs of different versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669305/how-does-jvm-deal-with-duplicate-jars-of-different-versions)

Answer (score 0):

There will be some problems . Sometimes the JVM might work fine but other times it might not recognise any of the jars .
Its better to have one jar in the classpath .

Comment: This CAN cause problems.  I've run into it first hand.  If you have the same dependency twice in your path, you can run into issues.  These issues are intermittent, and are a headache to track down the root cause.  Sometimes two versions of a jar may appear to be the same, but a class may have been rebuilt with a different jdk, or there may have been a code change.  Best not to leave this to chance, and only have it in there once.

Comment: Having 2 versions of the same jar is different than having the same version twice (which is the question here). If you have trouble with versions I recommend a modular system such as OSGi.